# Count number of dynamic rows and display it in input box in html

Tags: javascript, html

i have tried to count number of dynamic rows in html table in which when counting the rows it is also counting table head and i want to display number of rows in a input box.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".count").click(function(){            
        // Select all the rows in the table 
        // and get the count of the selected elements 
        var rowCount = $("#tbpnr tr").length; 
        var x = document.write(rowCount*280).innerHTML;
          return(x);
        document.getElementById("answer").value = x;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: We need the HTML too

Comment: `document.write(rowCount*200).innerHTML;` will not work. `return(x)` will not work. The last line of code will never be executed.

Comment: Please add your markup to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will count the number of rows in the table body and place the number of rows * 280 into the input element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".count").click(function() {
    var rowCount = $("#tbpnr tr").length;
    document.getElementById("count").textContent = rowCount;
    document.getElementById("answer").value = rowCount * 280;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbpnr">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class="count">Count</button>
<br>
Number of rows:
<b id="count"></b>
<br>
Number of rows * 280:
<input id="answer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` itself for adding count in the `input` box.
Try the below code for displaying count inside `input`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".count").click(function(){            
        // Select all the rows in the table 
        // and get the count of the selected elements 
        var rowCount = $("#tbpnr tr").length; 
        $("#answer").attr("value", rowCount*280)
    }); 
});
```

Please add HTML of the table for addressing the table header count issue.